# Solid aluminum powder

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I am curious if there is a way to dissolve or break down solidified aluminum powder. I have tried to break it apart but it is a solid chunk and I need to figure out how I can break it down to 150 pound pieces.

Can a block of hardened aluminum powder be physically or chemically broken down back to a soft form.

Comment: What do you mean by "solidified aluminium powder" ?

Comment: Can you modify your question? If you have a solid chunk, it doesn't make sense that you're trying to dissolve a powder.

Comment: Luke - I have a couple of questions: 1 Are you trying to get rid of it or trying to use it for an application? 2 How is this 150 mass organized i.e. in a too heavy to lift bucket or bag or ... ?  And then for physically breaking it apart, you could try rock grinders - will not powder the material but will make moving it easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a sealed container of aluminum powder that became exposed to air, your prospects for turning your current material back into aluminum powder are grim.

Your block probably appears like something that became clumpy when exposed to humidity (table salt, sugar, etc.), and that you aught to be able to just break it apart with a little force to get the powdery stuff again.

Unfortunately, aluminum reacts with the oxygen in air to form a very hard oxide layer, which is likely what is now binding the formerly pure aluminum powder together. In other words, you don't just have aluminum "sticking" to aluminum, but you've formed strong chemical bonds, actually creating a new compound altogether (aluminum oxide) There is likely no simple solution for returning your 150 pound blocks of mixed aluminum / aluminum oxide back into pure aluminum powder.